# SQL SELECTION SYNTAX

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in constructing a SQL query.

Here is my data in a simple two-column table:

```
    +----------+----------+
    | column 1 | column 2 |
    +----------+----------+
    |     a    |     0    |
    |     b    |     0    |
    |     b    |     1    |
    +----------+----------+
```

Column 2 is always only ever either "0" or "1"

I need a query which will obey this rule:

```
     If there are multiple records with the same value in column 1, 
     then I want ONLY the row that has value "1" in column 2.
```

So, in the above example, I would want only the first and third rows to be returned from my query

```
    +----------+----------+
    | column 1 | column 2 |
    +----------+----------+
    |     a    |     0    |   <<--- WANT this row 
    |     b    |     0    |
    |     b    |     1    |   <<--- WANT this row
    +----------+----------+
```

This seems to me to be a "maximum" of a bunch of "groups" problem.

Comment: What happen if column1 has multiple record with all 0 in column 2 ?

Comment: Or if there are multiple (b, 1) records.  Do you want all of those in your result set, or just one?

Comment: It seems like you might be oversimplifying your case here. Based on your comments here and in @user2989408's answer, it looks like you might have a more interesting problem to solve than this question would imply. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Oops. I just noticed that it wasn't the OP who commented in the answer comments.  But my thinking still stands... it seems like you might be trying to make it too easy for us here. This kind of two-column, two-value table seems rare in the wild!

Answer (score 3):

The OP states:

> ```
>  If there are multiple records with the same value in column 1, 
>  then I want ONLY the row that has value "1" in column 2.
> ```

This implies that if there are multiple records and none have a value of 1, then that value in column 1 should not be returned.  As an editorial comment, this doesn't sound reasonable to me, but it is what the OP states rather clearly.

This is easily produced from the aggregation query using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT t.column1, MAX(t.column2)
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.Column1
HAVING count(*) = 1 or MAX(t.column2) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct with your Maximum assumption. One way of doing this would be

```
SELECT t.column1, MAX(t.column2)
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.Column1
```

Comment: `then I want **ONLY** the row that has value "1" in column 2.` What if the values are all 0...

Comment: @GabrielL. Then his result should not have `(a, 0)`, but the question says he wants that row in the result.

Comment: Not right, because `a` is not duplicated, so it doesn't matter. As @Chris Farmer states, `This kind of two-column, two-value table seems rare in the wild!`.

Comment: @GabrielL. Maybe such tables do not exist, or maybe the OP simplified his problem. But that's what the OP has posted.